# При установке появляются 2 значка на любых устройствах

Tags: java, android

Пилил я своё приложение в Android studio, заметил при установке появляется 2 значка, как фиксить??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Вам в манифесте нужно указать одну активность которая будет запускаться по умолчанию. Вот например у меня в проекте активность экрана логина идет главной:

```
<activity
android:name=".LoginScr"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

у вас сейчас вероятнее всего в манифесте так:

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".MyActivityA" android:icon="@drawable/aicon"  android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyActivityB" android:icon="@drawable/bicon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

То есть по факту у вас есть две активности которые вы можете запускать по отдельности. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities) пример подобного вопроса.

**P.S.** На этом форуме желательно прикладывать код того что у вас есть, чтобы ваш вопрос не закрыли из-за проблем с качеством. Здесь есть такое замечание:

> Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа
>   поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что
>   вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно
>   демонстрирующий проблему.

Ознакомьтесь с правилами публикации вопросов, чтобы в дальнейшем у вас не было неожиданностей :)